# Rabbit MQ Connection Factory Connecting to Cluster with 2 nodes But separate queue names

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Below is my Rabbit setup configured form my middle-ware team.

1. A cluster having 2 nodes, each node has 1 Queue lets say, Node1 --> Sample.Q1 And Node2 --> Sample.Q2 
   Queues configured to have 50% of load on rabbit side.
2. Basically Sample.Q1 and Sample.Q2 receive same type messages, But 2 Queues are created on each host for more resilience and high availability.
3. I have requested them to keep the same queue across the Nodes, But my middle-ware team is confirmed that they can't create a duplicate queues on the same cluster.
   My question is How spring boot supports to create a connection factory and Rabbit listener.

I have code configuration as below, But that is not working I know this is not correct..

---

```
@Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory subscriberConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory subsCachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        subsCachingConnectionFactory.setAddresses(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberAddresses());  // host1:port, host2:port
        subsCachingConnectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberUsername());
        subsCachingConnectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPassword());
        subsCachingConnectionFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitMqConfig.getVhost());
        subsCachingConnectionFactory.setConnectionNameStrategy(f -> "subscriberConnection");
        return subsCachingConnectionFactory;
    }

@RabbitListener(id="messageListener",queues = "#{rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberQueueName()}",containerFactory="queueListenerContainer")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message, Channel channel, @Header("id") String messageId, 
            @Header("amqp_deliveryTag") Long deliveryTag) {

        LOGGER.info(" Message:"+ message.toString());
}

Queues are configured like Sample.Q1, Sample.Q2.
But this is not working.


----------
Error Log:
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'sample.q1,Hydra.clone.q2' in vhost 'Sample.services', class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:288)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'Sample.q1,Sample.q2' in vhost 'Sample.services', class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:516)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:670)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:597)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why don't you just use mirrored (HA) queues and let RabbitMQ take of it all for you?

Comment: @GaryRussell Yes, I have been suggested the same to middle-ware Architecture, But they said this setup is to achieve high resilience.
If this is case I need to have 2 listeners separately and co-ordinate the processing using executors.

Comment: It's not at all clear what your problem is; you will need to create 2 distinct connection  and listener container factories.

Comment: My Question is Do I need to create 2 Different Rabbit Listeners ?

Comment: You can add 2 `@RabbitListener`s to the method, with each one pointing to a different container factory. The framework will then create two containers with a single listener.

Comment: Okay, Let me try This.